# I2C inside a docker container

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am trying to use the i2c pins on a raspberry pi inside a docker container. I install all my modules using RUN but when I use the CMD to run my python program i get an error that says

```
Trackback (most recent call last):
file "test.py", line 124, in <module>
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I run this on my raspberry pi and not in my container it works fine. But when I turn off my i2c pins on my raspberry pi it gives me the same error when running it. So I know it has to do with my i2c pins being activated. Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a security precaution, system devices are not exposed by default inside Docker containers.  You can expose *specific* devices to your container using the `--device` option to `docker run`, as in:

```
docker run --device /dev/i2c-0 --device /dev/i2c-1 myimage
```

You can remove all restrictions with the `--privileged` flag:

```
docker run --privileged myimage
```

This will expose all of `/dev` to your container, and remove other restrictions as well (e.g., you will be able to change the network configuration in the container and mount new filesystems).

Comment: Any ideas about docker-compose?

Comment: Docker compose offers support for pretty much all of the `docker run` option.  See [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) for the equivalent of `--device`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the following in docker-compose (tested with v3 of docker-compose spec):

```
devices:  
  - "/dev/i2c-1:/dev/i2c-1"
```